# Custom view not found excpetion in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to capture the view not found exception (not the http route not found) in Laravel 5.2 and display a custom error?
I tried to capture InvalidArgumentException in app/Exceptions/handler and return a simple message with no luck.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why will there be any view not found exception?

Comment: I have a website that supports multiple languages. for example, let's say team page exists on the English side of the website. But in the Spanish side I don't have a team page. Since the website is dynamic, if somebody have the full url to the team route while he/she is using the Spanish version of the website, he/she will get page not found error because it does not exist for the Spanish version. So I would like to abort with a 404 error instead of view not found. The route is the same but the views are separate per language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include this in your `app\Exception\Handler.php` file's `render` method:

```
if($e instanceof InvalidArgumentException) abort(404);
```

Don't forget to `use InvalidArgumentException;` at the top of class.

**EDIT**: I can see this is a general Exception and lots of classes throwing it. So when some other class throws this Exception, you will still get 404.

So just a quick hack:

```
if(($e instanceof InvalidArgumentException) && str_contains($e->getFile(), 'Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder')) abort(404);
```

So this will only show 404 when FileViewFinder file throws InvalidArgumentException.

P.S May be there are better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. Instead of using InvalidArgumentException I used ErrorException. It's working now ;-)